# How put a legend in an animation?

Tags: plotting, export, legending, animation, gif-format

I wrote the following code for create an animation with legend: however I was not able to put the LineLegend command into the command Animate and so it seems that this is the reason for which I can't export the animation in a gif-animation. So I'd like know **how create a legend for an animation and how put it in a specific position and so finally how export it**: I point out that I have to export a row animation if possible. So to follow the code

```
Subscript[x, 0][j_] := 1 (*Ascissa iniziale del j-esimo punto*)
Subscript[y, 0][j_] := j(*Ordinata iniziale del j-esimo punto*)
x[t_, j_] := 
 Subscript[x, 0][
   j] (t^2 + 
    1)(*Legge orraria del j-esimo punto sull'asse delle ascisse*)
y[t_, j_] := 
 Subscript[y, 0][
   j] (t + 1)(*Legge oraria del j-esimo punto sull'asse delle \
ordinate*)
T[t_, j_] := {x[t, j], y[t, j]}(*Traiettoria del j-esimo punto*)
Color = {Red, Green, Blue};(*Lista colori*)
Trajectory[j_, i_, r_, g_, b_, o_, s_] := 
 Piecewise[{{ParametricPlot[T[t, j], {t, 0, i}, ImageSize -> Large, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Extract[Color, j]], 
    s == 0}, {ParametricPlot[T[t, j], {t, 0, i}, ImageSize -> Large, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[r, g, b], Directive[Opacity[o]]}], 
    s == 1}}]
P[t_, j_] := {PointSize[0.01], Point[T[t, j]]}(*Punto j-esimo*)
V[t_, j_] = {Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[{T[t, j], 
     T[t, j] + {D[x[t, j], t], 
       D[y[t, j], 
        t]}}]};(*Vettore velocità della j-esima traiettoria al tempo \
t*)
MotionPoints[n_, i_] := 
  Legended[Animate[
    Show[Table[Trajectory[j, i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], {j, n}], 
     Graphics[Table[{ V[t, j], P[t, j]}, {j, n}]], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 35}}], {t, 0, i}, 
    AnimationRate -> 0.3, AnimationRunning -> True], 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, 
      Blue}, {"Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \
\(1\)]\)=(1,1,0)", 
      "Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)=(1,2,0)", 
      "Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(3\)]\)=(1,3,0)"}, 
     LegendLabel -> Placed["TRAIETTORIE", Above], 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Below]];(*Animazione del moto*)
\[Xi][s_, t_, j_] := Exp[(2 t s)/(t^2 + 1) + Log[x[t, j]]]
\[Eta][s_, t_, j_] := Exp[s/(t + 1) + Log[y[t, j]]]
\[CapitalLambda][s_, t_, 
  j_] := {\[Xi][s, t, j], \[Eta][s, t, 
   j]}(*Linea di corrente del punto j-esimo all'istante t*)
Streakline[t_, j_] := 
 Piecewise[{{ParametricPlot[\[CapitalLambda][s, t, j], {s, 0, 3}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> 
      RGBColor[0.98, 0.85, 0.37]], (t - 0)*(t - 1)*(t - 2) != 
     0}, {ParametricPlot[\[CapitalLambda][s, t, j], {s, 0, 3}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> 
      Piecewise[{{Red, t == 0}, {Green, t == 1}, {Blue, 
         t == 2}}]], (t - 0)*(t - 1)*(t - 2) == 0}}]
StreaklineMotion[j_, i_] := 
 Legended[Animate[
   Show[Table[Streakline[h - 1, j], {h, 3}], 
    Trajectory[j, i, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1], Streakline[t, j], 
    Graphics[{ V[t, j], P[t, j]}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 35}}], {t, 0, i}, 
   AnimationRate -> 0.12, AnimationRunning -> True], 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue, 
     RGBColor[0.98, 0.85, 
      0.37]}, {"Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\
\) al tempo t=0", 
     "Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t=1 ", 
     "Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t=2", 
     "Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t"}, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Placed["LINEE DI CORRENTE DI \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \
\(1\)]\)=(1,1,0)", Above], LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
   Below]](*Animazione linee di corrente del j-esimo punto*)
Row[{MotionPoints[3, 5], , , , StreaklineMotion[1, 2]}]
```

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Replace `Below` with ```{0.5, 0.7}``` for both legends. p.s. your code does not compute, but I think it is computing at your end just fine. EDIT: It could be version dependent. I have 12.2.0. Animation is running but inside a red box.

Comment: Oh, fine: in this way the legend is put in the animation! However I can't not yet export it strangely: if I export the Out as a gif the there is no motion in the file. Anyway it seems I have 12.3.0 version: in the hard disk the Mathematica Directory is 12.3.

Comment: Next stop is this WRI [page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html). Also search this forum. There will be plenty of links. Apologies, it is running fine. I should know better to Quit->Kernel and start fresh.

Comment: Oh, I was aware of it: I tried to rename the command Row as Esercizio9 , that is Esercizio9=Row[{MotionPoints[3, 5], , , , StreaklineMotion[1, 2]}], and so I gave the command Export["Esercizio9.gif"Esercizio9] but unfortunately the file exported is a simple image without animation.

Comment: `m = Animate[
   Legended[
    Show[Table[Trajectory[j, i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], {j, n}], 
     Graphics[Table[{V[t, j], P[t, j]}, {j, n}]], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 35}}], 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, 
       Blue}, {"Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \
\(1\)]\)=(1,1,0)", 
       "Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)=(1,2,0)", 
       "Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(3\)]\)=(1,3,0)"}, 
      LegendLabel -> Placed["TRAIETTORIE", Above], 
      LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {0.5, 0.7}]], {t, 0, i}, 
   AnimationRate -> 0.3, AnimationRunning -> True];`

Comment: Make this change: Move Animate outside and Legended inside in both places,  then `Export["C:\\test.gif", m]` and the same thing for `n` or similar variable. Use a quick time player to see the animation or similar.

Comment: Really fine: it works perfectly. Thanks very much for the assistance!!!

Comment: @Syed Since your approach seems to have solved the OP's problem, please turn it into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(*Ascissa iniziale del j-esimo punto*)
Subscript[x, 0][j_] := 1 

(*Ordinata iniziale del j-esimo punto*)
Subscript[y, 0][j_] := j 

(*Legge orraria del j-esimo punto sull'asse delle ascisse*)
x[t_, j_] := Subscript[x, 0][j] (t^2 + 1)

(*Legge oraria del j-esimo punto sull'asse delle ordinate*)
y[t_, j_] := Subscript[y, 0][j] (t + 1)

(*Traiettoria del j-esimo punto*)
T[t_, j_] := {x[t, j], y[t, j]}

(*Lista colori*)
color = {Red, Green, Blue};
Trajectory[j_, i_, r_, g_, b_, o_, s_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {ParametricPlot[T[t, j], {t, 0, i}
     , ImageSize -> Large
     , AspectRatio -> 1
     , PlotStyle -> Extract[color, j]], s == 0
    }
   , {ParametricPlot[T[t, j], {t, 0, i}
     , ImageSize -> Large
     , AspectRatio -> 1
     , PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[r, g, b]
       , Directive[Opacity[o]]}], s == 1}}
  ]
(*Punto j-esimo*)
P[t_, j_] := {PointSize[0.01], Point[T[t, j]]}
(*Vettore velocità della j-esima traiettoria al tempo t*)

V[t_, j_] = {Arrowheads[0.03],
   Arrow[{T[t, j], T[t, j] + {D[x[t, j], t], D[y[t, j], t]}}]
   };

MotionPoints[n_, i_] := (mm = Animate[Legended[Show[Table[
        Trajectory[j, i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], {j, n}],
       Graphics[Table[{V[t, j], P[t, j]}, {j, n}]],
       PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 35}}
       ]
      , Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}
        , {"Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)=(1,1,0)"
         , "Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(2\)]\)=(1,2,0)"
         , "Traiettoria \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(3\)]\)=(1,3,0)"}
        , LegendLabel -> Placed["TRAIETTORIE", Above]
        , LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {0.5, 0.7}]]
     , {t, 0, i}
     , AnimationRate -> 0.3
     , AnimationRunning -> True]);

(*Animazione del moto*)
\[Xi][s_, t_, j_] := Exp[(2 t s)/(t^2 + 1) + Log[x[t, j]]]
\[Eta][s_, t_, j_] := Exp[s/(t + 1) + Log[y[t, j]]]

(*Linea di corrente del punto j-esimo all'istante t*)
\[CapitalLambda][s_, t_, j_] := {\[Xi][s, t, j], \[Eta][s, t, j]}

Streakline[t_, j_] := Piecewise[
  {{ParametricPlot[\[CapitalLambda][s, t, j], {s, 0, 3}
     , PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
     , ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1
     , PlotStyle -> 
      RGBColor[0.98, 0.85, 0.37]], (t - 0)*(t - 1)*(t - 2) != 0}, {
    ParametricPlot[\[CapitalLambda][s, t, j], {s, 0, 3}
     , PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
     , ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1
     , PlotStyle -> Piecewise[{
        {Red, t == 0}
        , {Green, t == 1}
        , {Blue, t == 2}}]]
    , (t - 0)*(t - 1)*(t - 2) == 0}}
  ]

StreaklineMotion[j_, i_] := (nn = Animate[Legended[Show[Table[
       Streakline[h - 1, j], {h, 3}]
      , Trajectory[j, i, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1]
      , Streakline[t, j]
      , Graphics[{V[t, j], P[t, j]}]
      , PlotRange -> {{0, 35}, {0, 35}}
      ]
     , Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue, RGBColor[0.98, 0.85, 0.37]}
       , {"Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t=0"
        , 
        "Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t=1 "
        , 
        "Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t=2"
        , 
        "Linea di corrente di \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) al \
tempo t"}
       , LegendLabel -> Placed[
         "LINEE DI CORRENTE DI \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \
\(1\)]\)=(1,1,0)", Above]
       , LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {0.5, 0.7}]]
    , {t, 0, i}
    , AnimationRate -> 0.12
    , AnimationRunning -> True])
(*Animazione linee di corrente del j-esimo punto*)
Row[{MotionPoints[3, 5], Spacer[8], StreaklineMotion[1, 2]}]
```

---

For the export:

```
Export["C:\\test_mm.gif", mm]
Export["C:\\test_nn.gif", nn]
```

---

[image]